# Is This A Formal Proof $f:Z \rightarrow N ; f(z)=|z|$ is onto and not 1-1?

Tags: functions

There will be a function $f(z)=|z|$ defined as follow $f:Z\rightarrow N$
Prove/Disprove the function is 1-1 or onto or both.

Disproving 1-1

$f(-1)=f(1)=1 \rightarrow $-1 does not equal 1
therefore by definition the function is not 1-1.

Proving onto

$Z= N+ \bigcup N-  $ onto means that $Img(f)=B$ in our case |Z|=N and that is true because |Z|=N

Comment: You show it is not 1-1. To show it is onto, consider an arbitrary element in $N$. Let us suggestively call it $n$. Then, is there a choice of $z \in Z$ such that $f(z) = n$? If so, what is your choice?

Comment: Your notation $Z= N+ \bigcup N-  $ is diffcult to understand, please use $(-\mathbb{N})$ (Bourbaki - but not only - notations) or $(\mathbb{Z}_{\leq 0})$ (used in combinatorics).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's at the very least a very sloppy proof. For 1-1, I would write:

> $f(-1) = 1 = f(1)$. Since $-1$ does not equals $1$, $\dots$.

(I.e., change the order in the equality to make it read naturally from left to right; get rid of the $\rightarrow$).

Those are details, though. For onto, there are notational problems: what do you mean by ${\mathbb Z} = {\mathbb N} + \bigcup {\mathbb N}$? What is $B$? What is $|{\mathbb Z}|$? (Don't answer - I can guess what you mean; my point is that it's sloppy).

More seriously, though, you're not giving an argument for onto. You say, essentially,

> $|{\mathbb Z}| = {\mathbb N}$ because $|{\mathbb Z}| = {\mathbb N}$.

What you need to do is take an arbitrary $n \in {\mathbb N}$ and show that it can be written as $|z|$ for some $z \in {\mathbb Z}$. It's trivial, of course, but that's what has to be done.